# What is the legality of scraping YouTube data?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, web-scraping

If we scrap youtube data and just display the content being scraped. Is it legal or illegal? The same question I want to ask regarding using YouTube API as well. Can anybody please suggest.

Comment: IANAL. [Youtube ToS](https://www.youtube.com/static?gl=GB&template=terms) 5.1.E, 5.1.H say no. I can't see such a restriction in [Youtube API ToS](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms). Violation of ToS by itself is not (or rather [should not](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/01/aarons-law-violating-a-sites-terms-of-service-should-not-land-you-in-jail/267247/)) be illegal, but it it is a contract violation; but you might be doing things that are also criminal, depending on how exactly you perform the said scraping (e.g. computer fraud for bypassing digital security).

Comment: I simply want to display the scraped content on my site. Not for promoting my site. simply displaying the contents for the end users

Comment: Sorry, misquoted. 5.1.C and 5.1.H (only access using YouTube player or other authorised mechanism; no automated scrapers that are faster than a human). You are free to embed content. You can't scrape it.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's their `robots.txt`: https://www.youtube.com/robots.txt

They aren't very welcoming of scraping which is also why YouTube is inherently difficult to scrape. You can embed data from YouTube no problem. If you do scrape it and embed it just don't make it obvious that you're scraping it.

Otherwise you're fine.